# Singly linked list create function C

Tags: c, singly-linked-list

I am currently trying to make function create() for singly linked list, where I am supposed to pass unlimited amount of parameters and it will pass the parameters as nodes' values. The code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

//define sllnode struct
typedef struct sllist
{
    int val;
    struct sllist *next;
}
sllnode;

sllnode* create(int count, ...);

int main(void)
{
    //here i try to print out values of this list
    sllnode* new_sllist = create(34,2,5,18);

    //print out values that I have assign using create() to test
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        printf("%i\n",new_sllist[i].val);
    }
}

//create function
sllnode* create(int count, ...)
{
    va_list list;
    int i;
    int arr[count];

    va_start(list, count);

    //create array arr that have all the values passed as parameters
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = va_arg(list,int);
    }

    //allocate memory for new singly linked list
    sllnode *sllist = malloc(count * sizeof(sllnode));

    //check if memory has been successfully allocated
    if(sllist == NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to allocate memory.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // loop through array arr and assign values to val and *next of each sllnode in new sllist
    for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
    {
        sllist[j].val = arr[j];
        sllist[j].next = &sllist[j+1];

        if(j == count - 1)
        {
            sllist[j].val = arr[j];
            sllist[j].next = NULL;
        }
    }
    return sllist;
    free(sllist);
}
```

But when I print out I only receive the last 3 values (2,5,18) and a number -23791193490 which differs each time (I suppose this has seeped into another part of memory). How do I do this correctly?

Comment: OT: You are allocating a single block of memory for `count` list elements, which makes it difficult to free individual elements after manipulating the list in various ways. It is more conventional to allocate memory for each element individually.

Comment: I think you should also not use a variadic function for this. It reeks of syntax fixation.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I am almost 3 weeks into my coding ventures and currently trying to follow the instructions on cs50. Can you give some suggestions on how I can make this better and achieve the same result (when passing unlimited parameters then create same amount of nodes)?

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `34` for the count parameter. Correct usage would be:

```
sllnode* new_sllist = create(4,34,2,5,18);
```